# How to fire c# Method when i click on tab using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have 3 tabs to load charts,
So I want data to be loaded with select of each tab,
it looks like that :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div id="tabs">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#tabs-1">First Tab</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second Tab</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third Tab</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div id="tabs-1">
                            <p>
                                This is Chart1
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tabs-2">
                            <p>
                                This is Chart2
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tabs-3">
                            <p>
                                This is Chart3
                            </p>
                            <p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

i want each tab click load one c# method

```
public void loadFirstTab()
{
     //load first Chart
}
public void loadSecondTab()
{
     //load Second Chart
}
public void loadThirdTab()
{
     //load ThirdChart
}
```

i tried using Ajax Call but static keyword makes it impossible!!!

***Edit***

the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST", 
contentType: "application/json; 
charset=utf-8", 
url: "myPage. aspx/TabClickAjax", 
data: "{activTab:activTab}", 
dataType: "json", 
success: function (msg) { } });
```

Web Method

```
public partial class mypage : System.Web.UI.Page 
{ [WebMethod] 
public static void TabClickAjax(string activTab) 
{ 
 If(activTab == "1" )
 {
    LoadFirstTab()
 }
} 
...
```

}

Comment: Can you explain “the static keyword” issue.

Comment: how can i call non static c# methods like(loadFirstTab,loadSecondTab,...) inside static web method? i tried this and it didn't work ?

Comment: Can you share this static method and from where it is being called? The Page class has all instance methods.

Comment: The ajax method :                                
    $.ajax({type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "myPage. aspx/TabClickAjax",
            data: "{activTab:activTab}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
            }
        });

Comment: public partial class mypage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ...
    [WebMethod]
    public static void TabClickAjax(string activTab)
    {
        If(activTab == "1" ) {LoadFirstTab()}
    }
    ...
}

Comment: Please add new code to the original question. Mark it as an update.

Comment: I still don’t see a static; static is a C# keyword, your last comment above is javascript.

Comment: I added it in the second comment, the problem is I can't call the method inside the static web method

Comment: Since you prefer to run serverside C# code and I see that you are already using the AJAX Control Toolkit (I see an UpdatePanel), I suggest you have a look at the Tabs control in this framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ajax updatepanel, you can simply convert to server control and work like normal asp.net control. (example below)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div id="tabs">
                        <ul>
                            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="Tab_Click">First Tab</asp:LinkButton></li>
                            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" OnClick="Tab_Click">Second Tab</asp:LinkButton></li>
                            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" OnClick="Tab_Click">Third Tab</asp:LinkButton></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div id="tabs1" runat="server">
                            <p>
                                This is Chart1
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tabs2" runat="server">
                            <p>
                                This is Chart2
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tabs3" runat="server">
                            <p>
                                This is Chart3
                            </p>
                            <p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

protected void Tab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch ((sender as LinkButton).ID)
    {
        case "LinkButton1":
            { /* Make Tab 1 active, do other stuff*/
                tabs1.Visible = true; tabs2.Visible = tabs3.Visible = false;
            }; break;
        case "LinkButton2":
            { /* Make Tab 2 active, do other stuff*/
                tabs2.Visible = true; tabs1.Visible = tabs3.Visible = false;
            }; break;
        case "LinkButton3":
            { /* Make Tab 3 active, do other stuff*/
                tabs3.Visible = true; tabs1.Visible = tabs2.Visible = false;
            }; break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

If you don't like this approach, you can use @M.Ramadan's answer above.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from you question the Ajax is already working with you however because of the static keyword you can't access other members of the page class.

I see first for all you need to remove the update panel as you are using ajax so update panel could break some javascript

Back to Ajax call you can pass the required parameters while sending the request so you can prepare your response without accessing other page members

For example: Suppose you have a textbox value to be used to filter result, you can simply add it to you ajax call

```
var filterValue = $('#txtbxID').val();

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    url:"myPage. aspx/TabClickAjax", 
    data: "{activTab:activTab,txtvalue:filterValue}", 
    dataType: "json", success: function (msg) { } 
});
```

And change the web method to accept the new parameter as

```
   public class MyPage: Page
  {
      [WebMethod]
      public static void TabClickAjax(ParametersObject par)
      {
          If(par.activTab == "1")
          {
              LoadFirstTab(par.txtValue)
          }
      }
  }


  public class ParametersObject
  {
      public string activTab;
      public string txtvalue;
  }
```

Comment: i passed activTab Value i need, i still don't understand how you call [  LoadFirstTab(par.txtValue) ] method inside static method!

Comment: Actually I meant LoadFirstTab is another static method. What I added here is the values that you need from the page members must be sent to the Ajax call

Comment: Could you clarify why you need it without statc? I mean give us the case study you have so we can help